# Prove that in the conjugate gradient method, ${d^{(k)}}^\top Qd^{(k)} = - {d^{(k)}}^\top Qg^{(k)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Let $f:\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow\mathbb{R},f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x^TQx-x^Tb}$, where $\mathbf{b \in \mathbb{R^n}}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$ is a real symmetric positive definte n$\times$n matrix.

How to show that in the conjugate gradient method for this $\mathbf{f}$, ${d^{(k)}}^\top Qd^{(k)} = - {d^{(k)}}^\top Qg^{(k)}$ ?

I have tried to use the relations: $0={g^{(1)}}^Td^{(0)}=-{g^{(1)}}^Tg^{(0)}$, to get $\beta_0=\frac{{g^{(1)}}^Tg^{(0)}}{{g^{(0)}}^Td^{(0)}}$. Since $\beta_0$ also equals to $\frac{{d^{(0)}}^TQg^{(1)}}{{d^{(0)}}^TQg^{(0)}}$ by the definite, so I tried to combine those two expressions but got no useful results.

Any guidance or comment is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula for computing the update direction $d^{(k)}$ in Conjugate Gradient Method:
\begin{equation}
d^{(k)} = -g^{(k)}+\frac{{g^{(k)}}^\top Qd^{k-1}}{{d^{(k)}}^\top Q d^{k-1}}d^{k-1}
\end{equation}
Since $d^{(k)}$ and $d^{(k-1)}$ is $Q$-conjugate, $d^{(k)}Qd^{(k-1)}=0$

Pre-multiply the above equation by $d^{(k)}Q$:
\begin{align*}
&d^{(k)}Qd^{(k)} = -d^{(k)}Qg^{(k)}+\frac{{g^{(k)}}^\top Qd^{k-1}}{{d^{(k)}}^\top Q d^{k-1}}d^{(k)}Qd^{k-1}
\\&d^{(k)}Qd^{(k)} = -d^{(k)}Qg^{(k)}
\end{align*}

Credit: An introduction to optimization, Chong, Zak p.g. 189